# recursive instances in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, typeclass

When using the following code, I get the error message below for the recursive usage of `toInt`

```
module Intro0 where
data Zero
data Succ n

class Nat n where
  toInt :: n -> Int
instance Nat Zero where
  toInt _ = 0
instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
  toInt _ = (1::Int) + toInt (undefined :: n)
```

I would have imagined finding toInt is trivial as it is specified in the context of the recursive instance, but I get a unification problem

```
Could not deduce (Nat n0) arising from a use of ‘toInt’
    from the context (Nat n)
      bound by the instance declaration
      at EPhantomTypes.hs:10:10-32
    The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Nat n => Nat (Succ n)
        -- Defined at EPhantomTypes.hs:10:10
      instance Nat Zero
        -- Defined at EPhantomTypes.hs:8:10
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘toInt (undefined :: n)’
    In the expression: (1 :: Int) + toInt (undefined :: n)
    In an equation for ‘toInt’:
        toInt _ = (1 :: Int) + toInt (undefined :: n)
```

I am not sure why this is. It looks trivial but I am not sure what to do with this.

Obviously `n` and `n0` should be the same but even using

```
instance forall n . (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
```

leads to the same error message

Comment: The `n` in `(undefined :: n)` isn't the same `n` as in `(Nat n) => Nat (Succ n)`. However, if you turn on `-XScopedTypeVariables` (or add `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of your file), they will be the same and everything compiles just fine.

Comment: of course, thank you for the explanation ! would you mind putting this as an answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem pertains to the scope of the variable `n`. In particular, the `n` in `(undefined :: n)` isn't the same `n` as in `(Nat n) => Nat (Succ n)`. If you would like to change this, you can enable  [`-XScopedTypeVariables`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables) (or add `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of your file), and then the two `n`s will be the same and everything compiles.